# `mix phx.server` command execution result is different between vscode and terminal

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to reload file's in the phoenix's project automatically. It is ok through terminal's `mix phx.server` command, but it get error through launch.json in vscode.

launch.json is as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "mix_task",
            "name": "mix (Default task)",
            "request": "launch",
            "task": "phx.server",
            "projectDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "mix_task",
            "name": "mix test",
            "request": "launch",
            "task": "test",
            "taskArgs": [
                "--trace"
            ],
            "startApps": true,
            "projectDir": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "requireFiles": [
                "test/**/test_helper.exs",
                "test/**/*_test.exs"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

vscode debug console output is as follows:

```
Started ElixirLS debugger v0.11.0
Elixir version: "1.13.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)"
Erlang version: "24"
ElixirLS compiled with Elixir 1.11.4 and erlang 22
[info] Running HelloWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.9.0 at 127.0.0.1:4000 (http)
[info] Access HelloWeb.Endpoint at http://localhost:4000
[watch] build finished, watching for changes...
[debug] Live reload: lib/hello_web/templates/hello/index.html.heex
```

web error message is as follows:
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

```
== Compilation error in file lib/hello_web/views/hello_view.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function HelloWeb.__using__/1 is undefined or private. However there is a macro with the same name and arity. Be sure to require HelloWeb if you intend to invoke this macro
    (hello 0.1.0) HelloWeb.__using__(:view)
    lib/hello_web/views/hello_view.ex:2: (module)
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:346: anonymous fn/5 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/7
```

If running through terminal, no such error message, terminal output is as follows:

```
macbook:hello yuchen$ mix phx.server
[info] Running HelloWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.9.0 at 127.0.0.1:4000 (http)
[info] Access HelloWeb.Endpoint at http://localhost:4000
[watch] build finished, watching for changes...
[info] GET /hello
[debug] Processing with HelloWeb.HelloController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 81ms
[debug] Live reload: lib/hello_web/templates/hello/index.html.heex
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
[info] GET /hello
[debug] Processing with HelloWeb.HelloController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 4ms
```

index.html.heex is as follows, I just delete one letter to test automatically module function

```
<section class="phx-hero">
  <h2>Hello World, from Phoenix cheny!</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that vscode takes elixir from a different place and in your terminal you have the correct elixir version, try to compare it by executing a elixir -v from your terminal.